# I wonder how to record GPU usage and write it in a file

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu

I wonder how to record GPU usage and write it in a file (for example json)? I'm using TensorFlow Keras to develop a text classifier. I already found `nvidia-smi` that only shows the memory usage, but I cannot record and write the usage.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252594